# Nodejs: How to read and traverse ServerResponse? (or, How to read client URL parameters?)

Tags: node.js, json, oauth-2.0, spotify, access-token

**User Flow:**

- User makes a post request to the server.
- The request redirects the user to Spotify's authorization endpoint, where he grants certain access to our web application.
- The user is redirected back to our website, and the URL in his address bar has now changed from `http://localhost:3000` to `http://localhost:3000/?code={code}`

We need to access this code.

My current approach is to console log the response returned.

This is what the console logs:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FII3_xrjb6lmTkma20TDjoyRXN_yKZ-knmFgFyfALKc/edit?usp=sharing

Same console log, without numbering:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/12qeVkp82opa2ITk0wGs8Fv0_Zej38OzUkJGRh8TzFfE/edit?usp=sharing

Scroll to line 1259, you would find this:

```
params: {},
 query:
      { code:
         'AQC_G...nzDFS'
},
```

How can we access the value of this 'code'?

Parsing it to JSON online (hoping to get the path to 'query'), it says, "Failed to parse invalid JSON format."

Also, this is the app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();

app.listen(3000, function() {
})

// The page to load when the browser (client) makes request to GET something from the server on "/", i.e., from the homepage.
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
  console.log(res); // This is logging that long ServerResponse.
});

let authURL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&scope=user-read-playback-state%20app-remote-control%20user-modify-playback-state%20user-read-currently-playing%20user-read-playback-position%20user-read-email%20streaming"

// Redirect user to Spotify's endpoint.
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  res.redirect(authURL);
});

// The data that server should POST when the POST request is sent by the client, upon entering the search queryValue, in the search bar (form).
app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  // The user input query. We are using body-parser package here.
  const query = req.body.queryValue;

  let searchUrl = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + query + "&type=track%2Calbum%2Cartist&limit=4&market=IN";

  //Using Axios to fetch data. It gets parsed to JSON automatically.
  axios.get(searchUrl, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': token,
      }
    })
    .then((resAxios) => {
      console.log(resAxios.data)



      //Extracting required data.



    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
});
```

This is the index.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="index-search-container">
      <form class="" action="/" method="post">
        <input id="queryId" type="text" name="queryValue" value="" placeholder="Search">
        <button type="submit" name="button">HIT ME</button>
      </form>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Notice the 'POST' method 'form' in index.js. This form is actually used to send queryValue to the server, to be returned with some data fetched from API. **In app.js, there are two app.post now, and only the first one works. Please help me improve the code.** :)

Comment: #1 Why user need to perform a post http invokation? #2 If your requierement is a web application in which user at login stage will be redirected to spotify,  accept the consent page and after that, receive the code to exchange by a valid access_token. A post is not required. This is a common oauth2 flow. Let me known to answer you

Comment: Thank you for replying. As of now, I am requiring the user to make post invocation, so he could be redirected to spotify's consent page.  I do not have (and do not want) a login page. The homepage is the search page, where the user enters `queryValue`. I do not want to ask for consent, 'just' as the website loads, it should be after the user wants to interact with the web app, that he is asked for consent. For example, when he searches for the first time, he is asked for consent, gets redirected back to search page. From now on, he can freely search for anything. Please guide.

Comment: #1 Is you search page a nodejs express app?  #2 Could your flow be like this? user enter to search.com, search something, is redirected to spotify, returns to search.com, perform some spotify operation with the access_token.

Comment: @JRichardsz #1 The search page is an index.html file, served by nodejs express app.js. As the user submits his search query, app.js renders results.ejs file to him, which contains data in a specified view format. #2 Yes, you got me right. This is what I desired the flow to be. But now, I feel this could be a better user experience: i) The user lands on the website. ii.) He submits the query. iii.) results.ejs file gets rendered to him. But the DIVs in which the API fetched data should be displayed says, "Please log in to spotify and grant access. iv.) Spotify consent page is displayed [contd.]

Comment: @JRichardsz v.) The user grants access and is redirected back to search page of the website. vi.) He submits query. vii.) results.ejs file is rendered back to him, but now the DIV's that contain the data, shows him the data that he asked for.

Comment: @JRichardsz I find it a better user experience because, along with the DIV's that contain Spotify fetched data, there is other information, contained in results.ejs file. So, if the user does not want to grant access, he should still be able to get the content that doesn't require him to grant access. This might also build his trust in the website, before he is sent to the consent page. Thank you so much for considering my question, sir. I'm sorry I couldn't reply earlier.

Comment: @JRichardsz This is the [Github Repository](https://github.com/1varunvc/Spotify). It doesn't yet contain the other data that I want to be displayed in the results.ejs file. That data would also be dynamic, fetched from YouTube API v3, with the same query value as the that the user has entered for Spotify.

Comment: @JRichardsz A point that I feel needs better clarification. When this DIV that says, "Please log in to spotify and grant access." is displayed (in point iii.) Clicking on that DIV, should send the user to the Spotify's consent page (point iv.)

Comment: When user clicks on the div "Please log in to spotify and grant access.", a redirect to spotify login will be performed. After user consent, user will be redirected to the initial page. In this case a post invocation is not required. #1 If your are agree, change the question tittle to something like this: How to get the access_token using authorization_code grant with spotify?  #2 Do you know the classic configuration steps in any oauth2 platform: consent page configuration, client/secret generation, origin and callback registration, etc   ?

Comment: @JRichardsz Okay. #1. If I were to change the title of the question, would the body of the question still fit? I'm an absolute beginner, I don't know. #2. I was taught of how to make API calls using the api_key, and I am totally new to the 'OAuth'-thing. For making (test) API calls, in order to build the project, I followed this article. https://benwiz.com/blog/create-spotify-refresh-token/ . I granted access for my public spotify account,  fetched the access_token and refresh_token (using cURL command.) Included a recurring get request in app.js to fetch new access_tokens using refresh_token.

Comment: #2 contd.] I didn't know that we need to get access tokens for every user, I thought I could use mine and refresh it. (This sounds silly to me now.) So, I'm not aware of the classic configuration steps in any oauth2 platform: consent page configuration, client/secret generation, origin and callback registration, etc. I did try watching tutorials on OAuth2.0 but I'm still pretty clueless. If you have any spare time, could you please actually fork the repo and maybe make required changes? I would be able to better understand the procedure then. I'm in no hurry, please consider whenever free.

Comment: The project is sufficiently documented with comments, it would require just one look from a professional like you to understand what's going on. :)

Comment: I found this package as well. https://github.com/JMPerez/passport-spotify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example you can use to ask for a user permissions to contact Spotify's API on their behalf:

```js
const express      = require("express")
const bodyParser   = require("body-parser")
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
const axios        = require("axios")
const crypto       = require("crypto")
/**
 * Environment Variables
 */
const PORT       = process.env.PORT       || 3000
const PROTOCOL   = process.env.PROTOCOL   || "http"
const URL        = process.env.URL        || `${PROTOCOL}://localhost:${PORT}`
const SEARCH_URL = process.env.SEARCH_URL || "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search"
const AUTH_URL   = process.env.AUTH_URL   || "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
const TOKEN_URL  = process.env.TOKEN_URL  || "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
const SCOPE      = process.env.SCOPE      || "user-read-playback-state app-remote-control user-modify-playback-state user-read-currently-playing user-read-playback-position user-read-email streaming"
/**
 * Spotify's Client Secrets
 */
const CLIENT_ID     = process.env.CLIENT_ID
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
/**
 * Memory Store
 */
const DB = {}
/**
 * Express App Configuration
 */
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use((_, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "*");
  next()
})
// Home
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200)
    .header("Content-Type", "text/html")
    .send(`
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Spotify Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<form id="searchForm">
  <input id="queryId" type="text" name="query" value="" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="submit" name="button">HIT ME</button>
</form>
<pre id="results">
<script>
const form$    = document.getElementById("searchForm")
const results$ = document.getElementById("results")
form$.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch("/", {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    body: JSON.stringify({query: e.target.elements.query.value})
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 301) {
        window.location.href = "/login"
        return
      }
      return response.json()
    })
    .then((data) => results$.textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err))
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
    `)
})
// Search
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.cookies.id
  if (id === undefined || DB[id] === undefined) {
    res.status(301).send()
    return
  }
  axios({
    url: `${SEARCH_URL}?q=${encodeURIComponent(req.body.query)}&type=track%2Calbum%2Cartist&limit=4&market=IN`,
    method: "get",
    headers: {"Authorization": `Bearer ${DB[id].access_token}`},
  })
    .then((response) => {
      res.status(200).json(response.data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
      res.status(400).send(err.message)
    })
})
// Login
app.get("/login", (_, res) => {
  res.redirect(`${AUTH_URL}?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=${encodeURIComponent(SCOPE)}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(URL + '/callback')}`)
})
// Callback
app.get("/callback", (req, res) => {
  const id   = crypto.randomBytes(9).toString("hex")
  const code = req.query.code
  axios({
    url: TOKEN_URL,
    method: "post",
    data: Object.entries({grant_type: "client_credentials", code, redirect_uri: URL})
      .map(([key, value]) => key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value)).join("&"),
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    auth: {username: CLIENT_ID, password: CLIENT_SECRET},
  })
    .then((response) => {
      DB[id] = response.data
      res.cookie("id", id, {maxAge: response.data.expires_in * 1000, httpOnly: true, path: "/"}).redirect("/")
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
      res.status(400).send(err.message)
    })
})
/**
 * Listen
 */
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`- Listening on port ${PORT}`))
```

You need to provide your `CLIENT_ID`, `CLIENT_SECRET`, and the redirect `URL` as environment variables. I suggest calling the `index.js` script like this:

```js
env CLIENT_ID=xxx \
env CLIENT_SECRET=zzz \
env URL=http://spotify.127.0.0.1.nip.io:3000 \
node index.js
```

The procedure is as follows:

1. A user sends a query through the form. Then, the server checks to see if it has given the app permissions to use Spotify's API. If not, it sends a redirect message.
2. The user authenticates with Spotify's credentials.
3. Spotify redirects the client to the site reference by the `redirect_uri` parameter.
4. We grab the `code` provided by Spotify, and we exchange it for the user's credentials by providing our `CLIENT_ID` and `SECRET_ID`.
5. We store those credentials in memory.
6. We redirect the client to the main site.

The next time the user runs a query, we'll have valid credentials, so we can query Spotify's API and return the results.

Comment: Thank you so much, kind sir.

Comment: It is going to take a while for me to understand every line. :D

Comment: If you believe it answer your question please mark it as correct. If another question arises, consider writing a new question.

Comment: Yes, this is probably what answers the question above. I'm not able to run it, it says, "INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI" upon entering query for the first time.

Comment: You have to configure the redirect URI at Spotify's developer dashboard. If you are accessing your app like: localhot:3000, you should add that, plus your callback endpoint. In my case /callback. I can guarantee it works if set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the callback URI to the Spotify app?
If yes create a route for that URI and you will be able to access the data returned by Spotify.

Comment: Yes, I added the callback URI to the Spotify app. After granting access, the user does get redirected to that URI which is localhost (as of now.) I have no idea as to what it is meant by creating a route for that URI, please guide me.